# Issue working with embed forms

Tags: php, jquery, twig, symfony-2.4

I'm working with embed forms in Symfony2. My main form is called "**inmovilizado_form**" and the collection is "**inmovilizado_concepto_form**". It works fine but I have an issue with jquery, when I click on "Añadir concepto" it adds 2 rows of inmovilizado_concepto_form and not one, as it should be. I can't guess where is the problem since I got the code from the official documentation. Below you can see an image showing the 2 "conceptos".

[image]

Here's my code:

**TWIG:**

```
<div class="form">
    {{ form_start(inmovilizado_form) }}
        <div class="input-box">
            {{ form_row(inmovilizado_form.proveedor) }}
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            {{ form_row(inmovilizado_form.anos) }}
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            {{ form_row(inmovilizado_form.fecha) }}
        </div>
        <div class="title">
             Conceptos
        </div>
        <div class="conceptos" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(inmovilizado_form.conceptos.vars.prototype)|e }}">
            {% for concepto in inmovilizado_form.conceptos %}
                {{ form_row(concepto.nombre) }}
                {{ form_row(concepto.base) }}
                {{ form_row(concepto.cantidad) }}
                {{ form_row(concepto.iva) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% block javascripts %}
                {{ parent() }}
            <script>
                var $collectionHolder;
                var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_concepto_link">A&ntilde;adir concepto</a>');
                var $newLinkLi = $('<div class="add_concepto"></div>').append($addTagLink);
            </script>
        {% endblock %}
        {{ form_row(inmovilizado_form.submit) }}
        {{ form_row(inmovilizado_form.cancel) }}
    {{ form_end(inmovilizado_form) }}
</div>
```

**JQUERY (1.9.1)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $collectionHolder = $('div.conceptos');

        $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

        $collectionHolder.find('.item').each(function() {
            addTagFormDeleteLink($(this));
        });

        $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

        $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });
});

function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {

     var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
     var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
     var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

     $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

     var $newFormLi = $('<div class="item"></div>').append(newForm);
     $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

     addTagFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
}

function addTagFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {

     var $removeFormA = $('<a href="#">Eliminar concepto</a>');
     $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

     $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $tagFormLi.remove();
      });
 }
```

Thanks in advance! This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Please, clarify your problem.

Comment: The problem is that everytime I click on the button "AÑADIR CONCEPTO", it adds 2 rows (conceptos) as you can see on the image. It should add only one... not 2. Thanks